# Speed improvement in string distance function

Tags: performance-tuning

I'm using this distance function to compare distance between strings:

```
distance[str1_String,str2_String] := Module[{split,r},
    split="*"<>#<>"*"&/@StringSplit@str1;
    r=N@Total[Boole@StringMatchQ[str2,#,IgnoreCase-> True]&/@split]/Length@split    
]
totalDistance[str1_String,str2_String]:=(distance[str1,str2]+distance[str2,str1])/2
```

`totalDistance` works just nice, but it's one order of magnitude slower than native distance functions like `EditDistance`.

Here is some code test:

```
testList=ConstantArray["Distance String Test with Mathematica",50000];
totalDistance["String distance test with MMA",#]&/@testList//AbsoluteTiming//First
EditDistance["String distance test with MMA",#]&/@testList//AbsoluteTiming//First
```

> 4.063474
>
> 0.433012

Some clue on how to optimize this code?

Comment: When I run your code, I get timings of 0.036450 and 
0.823406, respectively!  In other words, totalDistance, on my machine, runs 25X as fast as EditDistance.

Comment: I get the same as the OP on OS X, MMA v.9.

Comment: I just copied the code again and get my original result. There was an error in `totalDistance` that I had corrected some minutes ago. Maybe was it.

Comment: Strange. I continue to get the timings I reported on 2 hours ago, using your updated code. MMA v. 9.01 OS X.

Comment: Might be a difference between 9.0.1 and 9.0.0 then.

Comment: I have 9.0.1, OS X, and my timings agree with @Murta.

Comment: 9.0.1 on Win7, my timings agree with @Murta as well.